# Uniform limit (integral of a smooth function)

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence, smooth-functions

Divide the interval $[0,1]$ in $n$ subintervals of length $\frac{1}{n}$. Assign a color to each subintervals alternating black subintervals to white subintervals.

Call $B_n$ the union of all black subintervals and $W_n$ the union of all white subintevals.

Let $J:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ a smooth, symmetric function such that $\int_0^1J(x, y)\,dy\equiv 1$.

Is that true that

$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\left|\int_0^1J(x, y)\chi_{B_n}(y)\,dy-\frac{1}{2}\right|\xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{}0?$$

In other words is that true that
$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]}\left|\int_{B_n}J(x, y)\,dy-\frac{1}{2}\right|\xrightarrow[n\to +\infty]{}0?$$

Could someone explain me why?

I found that step on a paper but it is not clear for me (they say that it follows by the continuity of the function $J$).

Thank you!

Comment: What is the $\mathbb{I}$ for? Do you mean $J$ restricted to $B_n?$ If so, a more usual notation is just a vertical line: |.

Comment: I mean the characteristic function on the set $B_n$. In other words the integral is not done on $[0,1]$ but just on $B_n$.

Comment: In that case, a more standard notation is $\chi_{B_n}(y).$

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question!